# Cannot connect to MySQL server with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm new to PHP and MySQL and I need to make a project where I use databases. I looked up some piece of code that should connect to the database on localhost, but when I run it, I get a blank screen on my browser while the guy that explained the code didn't.

I use xampp for hosting Apache and MySQL servers

here is the code:

```
<?php
    define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');


    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    if(!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

    if(!$db_selected){
        die ('Cannot use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "connected successfuly!";

    mysql_close();
?>
```

sorry for being a noob.

EDIT:

```
$value = $_POST['question_input'];

$question = "INSERT INTO pitanja(pitanje_col) VALUES('$value')";

if(!mysql_query($question)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
}
```

question_input is the text input in the html form
pitanja is the table in the database
pitanje_col is the column in the database

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_` functions, they're deprecated. Instead use `mysqli_` or `PDO`. I don't understand why so many people keep making this mistake.

Comment: Which Php version are you using.

Comment: Check your PHP error log.

Comment: @Phalame please post the error here and almost at least 1 screenshoot, and check: mysql it's really running? If you try connect directly it's ok? (mysql tools / mysql query / mysql workbench)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should function properly. However, you need to be sure that you replace all the "DB_NAME"s with your actual database name. Otherwise, it won't connect properly. Additionally, before you can even use this, you must set up a new database and table using phpmyadmin. There is standard format for this setup that you should look into. (also ensure that your DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD is correct)

You could incorporate some pdo... the input would look something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $usertable 
(firstName, lastName, streetAddress) 
VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :streetAddress)";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(':firstName' => $firstName,
':lastName' => $lastName,
':streetAddress' => $streetAddress));
```

The words after the colons represent your column names.. (fill in necessary variables accordingly)

Comment: I checked my DB name multiple times and I didn't put a password for the user root. I've created a database and a table too. This is linked to a html form, i will edit my original post now to add the part of inserting data to the tables

Comment: I edited my post a bit to include some additional help.

Comment: It's now done -- that should work unless mysql isn't running :)